# jQuery facebox not working with Dynamic Drive Ajaxtabs

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs, facebox

This problem has been bugging me for a few days now and could really do with your input...

I am using http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxtabscontent/ajaxtabs_suppliment3.htm to create ajax tabs for my site and also using http://defunkt.io/facebox/ for modal windows. But when I am trying facebox links loaded through the ajax tabs, then its not loading the contents into facebox. But its working fine for any links outside the ajax tabs (ie. that load with PHP straight onsite as the site loads).

Any idea? Please need help on this to finalize my site...

Thank you all in advance

George

Below is my facebox jquery code:

```
enter code here

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.embed-thumbnail').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.facebox($(this).parent().find('.embed-content')[0].innerHTML)
});
$.facebox.settings.loadingImage = '../static/img/loading.gif'
$.facebox.settings.closeImage = '../static/img/closelabel.png'
$.facebox.settings.opacity = 1
$.facebox.settings.faceboxHtml = '\
<div id="facebox" style="display:none;"> \
<div class="popup"> \
<div class="content"> \
</div> \
<a href="#" class="close"><img src="../static/img/closelabel.png" title="close"    class="close_image" /></a> \
</div> \
</div>'
});
</script>
```

Ajaxtab code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var countries=new ddajaxtabs("popularPosts", "populardivcontainer")
countries.setpersist(true)
countries.setselectedClassTarget("linkparent") //"link" or "linkparent"
countries.init()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like you'll need to rebind the Facebox once the Ajax has loaded.

So with the ajax tabs, use the:

```
instance.onajaxpageload=function(pageurl){
//custom code here
}
```

and:

> Attach It onLoad
>
> While calling facebox() on any anchor tag will do the trick, it's
>   easier to give your Faceboxy links a rel="facebox" and hit them all
>   onLoad.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
})
```

So you should end up with something like:

```
instance.onajaxpageload=function(pageurl){
 $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
}
```

Obviously replacing "instance" with your tabs object - This should rebind the newly loaded Facebox elements to the code.

One thing the documentation doesn't make clear is if the `.onajaxpageload` method is once it has finished loading the Ajax content, as this is what you want (not during or before).

Edit:

New script to try.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var countries=new ddajaxtabs("popularPosts", "populardivcontainer") 
  countries.setpersist(true) 
  countries.setselectedClassTarget("linkparent") //"link" or "linkparent" 
  countries.init() 

$(document).ready(function() { 
   loadFacebox();

   countries.onajaxload=function(pageurl) {
     loadFacebox();
   };
}); 

function loadFacebox() {
  $('.embed-thumbnail').click(function(event) { 
event.preventDefault(); 
$.facebox($(this).parent().find('.embed-content')[0].innerHTML) 
}); 
$.facebox.settings.loadingImage = '../static/img/loading.gif' 
$.facebox.settings.closeImage = '../static/img/closelabel.png' 
$.facebox.settings.opacity = 1 
$.facebox.settings.faceboxHtml = '\ 
<div id="facebox" style="display:none;"> \ 
<div class="popup"> \ 
<div class="content"> \ 
</div> \ 
<a href="#" class="close"><img src="../static/img/closelabel.png" title="close"    class="close_image" /></a> \ 
</div> \ 
</div>' 
};
</script>
```

Or something like that... You may need a more cunning way to locate your facebox elements - however that should rebind the same code after each time a tab has loaded.

Comment: Also, should the tabs your using not work out, you can always check out the jQuery UI tabs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Comment: thanks for the answer... Can i kindly ask for some more guidance on where to place your code please? I will edit the original post and add my facebox jquery code on my site

Comment: The `.onajaxpageload` is for the ajax tabs. If you can post that code as well that would be good. You'll need to assign the tabs to a variable when you load them, as per the example you gave here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxtabscontent/ajaxtabs_suppliment3.htm - i.e. `countries.onajaxpageload=...` This will all go in the script tags at the top of your page as per usual.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help... added the code but facebox still doesnt fire up... where you have (pageurl) do i leave as is or place the url there?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I've updated once more with the correct variable for the ajax tabs (`countries`). the `pageurl` variable passed to the function is the url of the ajax tab content, this can be used for conditional statements (i.e. you want to do something specific when you load a specific tab), however in this scenario we'll want to fire the `loadFacebox()` function every time a tab loads.

Comment: Also, could you put a couple of `alert("some text");` in the function calls etc... So we can make sure it's all firing as expected and in the right places?